How to use standalone angular storybook component in another standalone angular storybook component
Created Icon storybook component and converted this to standalone component.Want to use this IconComponent in Alert Storybook Component.
below is icon.stories.ts file
import { Meta, StoryFn, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { IconComponent } from './icons.component';
import { withTests } from '@storybook/addon-jest';
import * as results from '../../../../.jest-test-results.json';
import { evaIcons } from './evaicons';
import { ToastComponent } from './toast.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

const meta: Meta<IconComponent> = {
  title: 'Atoms/Icons',
  component: IconComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule, ToastComponent],
      
    }),
    withTests({ results })
  ],
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    copyToClipboard: { action: 'clicked' }
  },
  render: (args: IconComponent) => ({ props: args })
};

export default meta;

below is Alert.stories.ts file in imports array i have added IconComponent
import { Meta, Story, moduleMetadata } from '@storybook/angular';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AlertComponent } from './alert.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { IconComponent } from '../icons/icons.component';
export default {
  title: 'Alert',
  component: AlertComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [BrowserAnimationsModule, MatButtonModule, IconComponent, AlertComponent],
    })
  ],
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    onButtonClick: { action: 'clicked' }
  },
  parameters: {
    docs: {
      description: {
        component: 'Your Alert component description goes here.'
      }
    }
  }
} as Meta;

